# javascript exec of curl piped to tar hits error

Tags: javascript, node.js, curl, tar

I have a shell command to download and untar a file, executed from javascript.  When done as curl piped to tar, this occassionally fails:

```
const child_process = require('child_process');
var cmd = `curl -s ${file} | tar -xj --strip-components=1 --exclude=README.txt -C ${directory}`;
child_process.exec(cmd, function commandCallback(error, stdout, stderr) {
      console.log('done downloading ' + type + ' bundle');
      if (error) {
        console.error('error downloading ' + type + ' bundle: ' + error);
        console.log(stderr);
      }
```

with errors like

```
Error: Command failed: curl -s https://dist.whosonfirst.org/bundles/whosonfirst-data-locality-latest.tar.bz2 | tar -xj --strip-components=1 --exclude=README.txt -C /mnt/storage-proc2/users/jeremy/pelias_metal/data/whosonfirst    
bzip2: Compressed file ends unexpectedly;
        perhaps it is corrupted?  *Possible* reason follows.
bzip2: Inappropriate ioctl for device
        Input file = (stdin), output file = (stdout)
```

but if the command is done as such

```
var cmd=`wget -q ${file} && tar -xj --strip-components=1 --exclude=README.txt -C ${directory} -f latest.file `;
```

Then it runs fine .  Does anyone know what's causing the first command to fail? Piping directly to tar can save quite a bit of time and disk space and would thus be preferable.

Node.js apparently has issues with buffers filling on long downloads if the -s flag is not passed to curl, but that doesn't seem to be the issue here, since the -s flag is present.

edit - it looks like javascript is not the culprit:

```
jeremyr@w6:~/pelias_metal/whosonfirst$ curl -s https://dist.whosonfirst.org/bundles/whosonfirst-data-postalcode-jp-latest.tar.bz2 | tar -xj --strip-components=1 --exclude=README.txt -C /mnt/data_science/pelias_w6/data/whosonfirst && mv /mnt/data_science/pelias_w6/data/whosonfirst/whosonfirst-data-postalcode-jp-latest.csv /mnt/data_science/pelias_w6/data/whosonfirst/meta 

bzip2: Compressed file ends unexpectedly;
        perhaps it is corrupted?  *Possible* reason follows.
```

and also `wget -q -O | tar` does work -

```
jeremyr@w6:~/pelias_metal/whosonfirst$ wget -q -O - https://dist.whosonfirst.org/bundles/whosonfirst-data-postalcode-jp-latest.tar.bz2|tar -xj --strip-components=1 --exclude=README.txt -C /mnt/data_science/pelias_w6/data/whosonfirst
jeremyr@w6:~/pelias_metal/whosonfirst$
```

Comment: Does it work if you run the command from the shell?

Comment: In the second command you're not redirecting the output of one command to the other. The problem (I think) with your first command is that you just can't use `|` as you would in any shell. You have to spawn a curl process and a tar process and manually redirect the output of the curl process to the input of the tar process.

Comment: @customcommander  the thing is this works for many cases, and seems to break just for large files

Comment: @barmar good question I will try to eliminate javascript as the culprit

Comment: @barmar , see edit in question - javascript isnt the culprit, it seems

Comment: In that case, this question might be more appropriate for [unix.se] or [su]. It's just about piping `curl` to `tar`, not about programming.